# Update primary source campaign trigger

Tags: trigger

Below is the code i have written to update primary source campaign in opportunity, This trigger will assign same campaign(same as opportunity name) name to opportunity primary source campaign . I am getting an error not sure what to do.

```
trigger Opps on Opportunity (before update) {


string oppname;
Set<Id> campaigns = new Set<Id>();
       for(Opportunity c : trigger.new)
       {    
          campaigns.add(c.id);
       }

       List< Opportunity > campaignlist = [Select id,Name,CampaignId from Opportunity where id = :campaigns];
        for(Opportunity campaign: campaignlist)
        {

oppname = campaign.name;
List<Campaign> elist = [Select id,Name from Campaign where Name = : oppname];
        for(campaign event: elist)
        {
             if(event.name==oppname)
             {  
               campaign.CampaignId = event.id;
             }
         }



       }
       update campaignlist;

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Comment: first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 0061100000Bw8vC) is currently in trigger Opps, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []: Trigger.Opps: line 28, column 1

Comment: Maybe check out this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122067/how-can-i-access-the-primary-campaign-source-field-for-a-campaign-member?s=5|2.5708

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are killing yourself with variable names -- `campaignList` should be used for a list of `campaign`, not `Opportunity`; `c` should be used to loop thru `Campaigns`, not `Opportunities`; and finally you can't update Opportunities (called `campaignList` in your code) in a before update trigger on Opportunity,

Here is a simpler approach ... (assumes campaign name/oppo name is a case sensitive match)

```
trigger updateCampaigns on Opportunity (before update) {
  map<String,Opportunity> oppoNameToOppoMap = new map<String,Opportunity>();
  for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new)
     oppoNameToOppoMap.put(o.name,o);

  for (Campaign c : [select id, name from Campaign 
                      where name IN : oppoNameToOppoMap.keySet]) {
      Opportunity matchingO = Trigger.newMap.get(oppoNameToOppoMap.get(c.name).id); // locate Oppo
      matchingO.campaignId = c.id;  // update, because in Trigger.new, implicit DML saves value
  }

}
```

Comment: Tried that but primary source campaign(CampaignId) is not getting copy from campaign.

Comment: @puravthakkar His code looks good, Is your Campaign name the same name as your Opportunity name?

Comment: code relies on case sensitive match -- do campaign name and oppo name match character for character? small edit made in code as well (my bad)